# DevicePolicyManager lockNow not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the checked lockNow implementation in API demos & tried the same thing in my app. But I am not able to lock the device(Google nexus)

Is there any restriction on this API call for thrid party application. isAdminActive() method is returning me false...

One mlore doubt,how to implement screen lock functionality for below 2.3 devices as there in no direct APIS for tat..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version you use but this API method (lockNow) is not functional since ICS (4.0), because of a bug I guess.

Check http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26599 and fav it, maybe they will fix it.